# Deleting braches on git combined by grep not working as expected

Tags: git, shell, unix, terminal, grep

I have a couple of branches that match `'release-*'` pattern. The branch can be deleted individually as `git branch -d release-01` which works. But the `git branch | grep '<pattern>' | xargs git branch -d` gives me error as `branch not found`:

```
error: branch 'release-02' not found.
error: branch 'release-03' not found.
```

[image]

What could be the reason for this ?

Comment: may be try with `xargs -t` to see what command is being executed... and also, in regex `*` means matching zero or more of previous character... it is different from `*` used in globbing... since `grep` anyway print entire line when match is found, just use `grep 'release-'`

Comment: Yes, it displays the right command but followed by the same error.

Comment: hmm, no idea then..

Comment: Thank you anyways

Comment: Weird! I am executing exactly the same steps (names, and commands) and "works on my machine" :(, but I am using a mac.

Comment: I am on Mac as well. Well, its the same unix engine, same git i suppose we all are using.

Comment: Try `| xargs -i git branch -d {}`.

Comment: Figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with grep mark up text color. I have grep aliased as `--color=always`. So, temporarily disabling the grep mark up text color worked for me.

```
git branch | grep --color=auto 'release-*' | xargs git branch -d
```

[image]